# Getting User memory error for generation chart

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap

I'm trying to get Pixel area covered by NDSI but when Generate the chart, I get memory error I don't know why it is coming on larger area but not on smaller area.
the code is.

```
var allAreas = snowcover_lst.map(function (ele) {
  var image2 = ee.Image(ele).gte(1);
  var snowcover = ee.Image(ele).clip(AOI)
                    .updateMask(image2.eq(1));
  var classes = snowcover.reduceToVectors({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
    geometry: AOI, 
    scale: 500,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
  var feats_area = ee.FeatureCollection(classes);
  var snowArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: feats_area,
    scale: 500,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
  return snowArea.get('area');
});

var chart = ui.Chart.array.values({array: allAreas, axis: 0, xLabels: allDates})
print(chart);
```

The complete script is: https://code.earthengine.google.com/5174a5d4cf67411e33b9e3757276e3e0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run out of memory when calculating `allAreas`. It's expensive to `reduceToVectors()`, so that's something you want to avoid unless you really need it. If I understand your script correctly, you simply want to calculate the area of pixels where `NDSI_Snow_Cover > 1`. If that's the case, there's no need to reduce to vectors.

You are also redundantly calling `clip(AOI)`. It can be quite costly for complex geometries, and something you try to use it sparingly. In your case it shouldn't be needed. This has a smaller impact than reducing to vectors though.

```
var snowCoverCollection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')
  .filterDate('2012-01-01', '2012-12-31')
  .select('NDSI_Snow_Cover')

var allAreas = snowCoverCollection.map(function(snowCover) {
  var snowArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6)
    .updateMask(snowCover.gte(1))
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: AOI,
      scale: 500,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    })
  return ee.Feature(null, snowArea)
    .set('date', snowCover.date())
})

var chartArea = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: allAreas, 
  xProperty: 'date', 
  yProperties: 'area'
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/02ed0994829902926c0fb3a42a3d803b

Comment: What if we want to do it for weekly and monthly?  how we will do it?